# Displaying text different than DataTextField in a RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding, radiobuttonlist

I try to develop a web based survey creation and filling app on ASP.NET and C# getting data from Sql Server. I use **DataBind** to bind my question names and answers. Below in the picture, I need to show **only the question number (like 1, 2, 3 etc.)** in RadioButtonList (not with the question name) and **only the question name** in a label lblQuestion as;

```
protected void rbtnQuestions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        General.myquestionid = System.Convert.ToInt32(rbtnQuestions.SelectedValue);

        lblQuestion.Text = rbtnQuestions.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

I also need the "id" of survey_question table to display the answers below the question since I use it in **SelectedIndexChanged** event.

[image]

But since I use **DataTextField**, both **RadioButtonList text** and **lblQuestion.Text** show the same thing. My way of binding the data is below:

```
string sqlStr = "SELECT id, question_no, question, survey_answer_type_id FROM survey_question WHERE survey_id = '" + General.mysurveyid + "'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, connection);
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(data);

rbtnQuestions.DataSource = data;
rbtnQuestions.DataTextField  = "question";
rbtnQuestions.DataValueField = "id";
rbtnQuestions.DataBind();
cmd.Dispose();
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Page load event Set

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string sqlStr = "SELECT id,question_no, CONVERT(varchar(10),(ROW_NUMBER()  over (order by question desc))) AS QueNo,question, survey_answer_type_id FROM survey_question WHERE survey_id = '" + General.mysurveyid + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, connection);
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(data);

        ViewState["data"] = data;
        rbtnQuestions.DataSource = data;
        rbtnQuestions.DataTextField = "QueNo";
        rbtnQuestions.DataValueField = "id";
        rbtnQuestions.DataBind();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And Question Set On SelectedIndexChanged Event

```
protected void rbtnQuestions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["data"];

    DataRow[] row = ds.Tables[0].Select("id = '" + rbtnQuestions.SelectedValue + "'");
    lblQuestion.Text = row[0]["question"].ToString();        
}
```